# Component of Angular App is not displayed in Internet Explorer Browser. Single-spa error

Tags: internet-explorer, virtual-directory, single-spa-angular

Virtual directory of the main app is not loaded and single-app error is thrown in IE. Everything works properly in other browsers. Probably someone has faced the same issue.
[about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7sjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the shared [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7sjT.png) is not giving an idea about the cause of the issue.

As per the official document of [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview/#how-hard-will-it-be-to-use-single-spa), single-spa works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, and IE11 (with polyfills).

So if you are using any lower versions of IE browser than IE 11 then it may not work properly.

As per this [document](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#internet-explorer), if you need to support IE11 or older, do the following:

- [Add core-js polyfill](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#polyfills)
- Remove arrow functions from index.html ([example](https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends/commit/22cbb2dc1c15165c39b10aa4019fe517fa88af32#diff-07a3141209aa56f89a0f47490866f94eR34))
- Change angular.json target to es5 ([example](https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends/commit/22cbb2dc1c15165c39b10aa4019fe517fa88af32#diff-acbfc718bf309f27dd3699a4ad80a2d1R13))

If you have not configured the above-mentioned changes then you can make a test with it. It may help to fix the said issue.